# issue with UpsertDE "Unable to retrieve security descriptor for this frame"

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, upsert, if

I'm trying to write results in a Data Extension but this is the message response in the cloud page

{"message":"Unable to retrieve security descriptor for this frame.","description":"System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to retrieve security descriptor for this frame. - from mscorlib\r\n\r\n"}

this is my code

```
 if (tags == "16") {
      var column = ["BlockKeys", "AssetType", "EmailName", "Tag"];
      var columnValues = [blockKeys, assetName, emailName, tags]; 
      var rows = Platform.Function.UpsertDE("Bloques", blockKeys,  column, columnValues);
  }
```

The variable "column" has the columns there are in the Data extension "Bloques".

The variable "columnValues" ​​has the variables with the respective values that I got in other part of the code. This variables works ok

I think my error is in the arrays or in the UpsertDE, someone knows what is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing a parameter in your UpsertDE call. It should have 5 parameters and you only have 4. (**[ref](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/ssjs_platformDataExtensionUpsertDE.html)**)

[image]

It should be something like:

```js
 var rows = Platform.Function.UpsertDE("Bloques", blockKeys, blockKeysValues, column, columnValues);
```

Where `blockKeysValues` is the values that you want to filter on in the same order as the Names listed out in `blockKeys`.

Comment: `if (tags == "16") {
  var rowsUpdated = UpsertDE("Bloques_de_componentes", ["Keys", "EmailName"], [blockKeyValue, emailName], ["AssetType", "Tag"], [assetName, tags]);
}`
i thought is not required de 3th.
 I change in this way but now the message error is **"Object expected: UpsertDE"**

Comment: @Juan That is a typo on the documentation. All 5 are required as far as I know.  As to your error, you need to change `UpsertDE` to `Platform.Function.UpsertDE`